# SQL Find unique items AND one of the column value is NULL

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I have a table w/ the format like below:

```
ItemNo  ItemDesc
11111   Item01 Description
11111   Item01 Description2
11111   <NULL>   
22222   <NULL>    
33333   Item03 Description
33333   Item03 Description2
33333   <NULL>
```

I'd like to find the unique item 22222.  TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ItemNo
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    ItemNo
HAVING
        COUNT(*) = 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN ItemDesc IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Comment: I would use `COUNT(*) = 1 AND COUNT(ItemDesc) = 0`.

Comment: COUNT(*) = 1 AND COUNT(ItemDesc) = 0 does not work

Comment: How do I display other columns like ItemDesc?

Comment: @bachphi - join the query's result back on to the source table... `SELECT yourTable.* FROM yourTable INNER JOIN (the-query-above) AS empties ON empties.ItemNo = yourTable.ItemNo`